# Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder 4.0 doesn't support Multi Stream with KCL 2 Enabled

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

KCL 2 allows multi stream support with the same consumer group in the same application.

With cloud stream kinesis binder 4.0, `kpl-kcl-enabled: true` A single stream in the destination works.

```yaml
bindings:
   kinesis-read-binding:
      destination: stream1
      group: consumergroupname
      binder: kinesis
```

The lease table defines the `leaseKey` as `shardId`.

When trying to read multiple streams on a single binding with the consumer group as shown below, the application runs in faulty mode by overriding the leases for the other stream shards.

```yaml
bindings:
   kinesis-read-binding:
      destination: streamA,streamB
      group: consumergroupname
      binder: kinesis
```

I have looked in the source code to look at the possible error, below is the cause that I think is the problem.

When not in multiplex mode, the `BindingService` iterates over each stream name in `bindConsumer` function and creates a different instance of `KCLMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` from the `bindConsumer`.
Due to the same, the `leaseKey` defined in the table doesn't use the  `MultiStreamTracker` hence overrides the shard for other streams.

With `multiplex` mode, `KCLMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` should be called with multiple streams, but fails much before due to

```yaml
bindings:
   kinesis-read-binding:
      destination: streamA,streamB
      group: consumergroupname
      binder: kinesis
      consumer:
         multiplex: true
```

`KinesisStreamProvisioner`.  The `KinesisStreamProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination()` fails and throws exception.

```java
// In KinesisStreamProvisioner.java the below statement throws Error from the createOrUpdate function
// name = "streamA,streamB"
return new KinesisConsumerDestination(name, createOrUpdate(name, shardCound));

private List<Shard> createOrUpdate(String stream, int shards) {
try{
// the below statement fails. stream = "streamA,streamB"
  shardList = getShardList(stream).join()
   ..
   ..
}
```

The above doesn't allow spring cloud stream kinesis binder to run with MultiStream Mode supported by KCL 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder: we just miss to handle that `multiplex` option in the logic you are mentioning.

Please, raise a GH issue and we will address it as soon as possible.

Comment: Have just pushed the fix: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/commit/4098381e1b0cdfc7964f695c6682f9bc6532ebbc. Feel free to try `4.0.1-SNAPSHOT`! I'm going to release it in a couple weeks after my vacation.

Comment: I have tried to use the SNAPSHOT as suggested. The application starts and the ```leaseKey``` is set as `STREAM_NAME:SHARD_ID` in the LeaseTable. But the Enhanced Fan out consumer doesn't get registered. There is one more fix required. The ```MultiStreamTracker``` interface implementation in the ```KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter``` doesnt correctly create the StreamConfigs. The ```ConfigBuilder``` should use the ```StreamSerIdentifier.multiStreamInstance``` instead. For Multi Stream Enhanced Fan Out Consumer, ARN is needed instead of just stream name,

Comment: Upon further debugging, The Method ```StreamIdentifier multiStreamInstance(String streamIdentifierSer)```expects an ARN in case of multi stream, but fails to find and thus throw an ```IllegalArgumentException```. 
While building the `MultiStreamTracker`, the streamIdentifier should have the full ARN to solve the issue in the Stream Config.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! Would you mind to provide a required fix as a contribution?

Comment: This would require a fixes in pring-integration-aws and spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder.  I can try.

Comment: I think the fix is only for SI-AWS. We have to implement tracker the way to resolve ARN against stream name from Kinesis client. Not clear what is `epoch`, but we can have some simple counter or just `0` for time being

Comment: the fix is added in SI-AWS in the PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/pull/234.
Can you release a new version of spring cloud stream kinesis binder to support the same.

Comment: The release is planned for the next week.

Comment: Thank you @Artem, the latest aws cloud stream kinesis binder supports the feature now. Fix is available in v4.0.1.